# Uploadify is not working

Tags: php, jquery, forms, uploadify

I am using uploadify to upload multiple files on my website, but it is not working properly. I have fix various things in it but it is not working properly. issue is that when i upload the file it will show me the loading bar and when it completes it disappear but when i check the destination the file is not present in it. Please help me. My code is given below:

index.php

```
<form>
        <div id="queue"></div>
        <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
    </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php $timestamp = time();?>
            $(function() {
                $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                    'formData'     : {
                        'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                        'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                    },
                    'swf'    : 'uploadify.swf',
                    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'

                });
            });
        </script>
```

uploadify.php

```
    <?php


    // Define a destination
    $targetFolder = 'uploads/'; // Relative to the root

    $verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

    if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
        $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

        // Validate the file type
        $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            echo '1';
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid file type.';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: check permissions on server ?

Comment: i don't know how i check permission on server?? can u please guide me in this case?

Comment: try to copy a file by php code ..

Comment: create a file on server and make a copy of that file with other name by php code .. simple file operations ..

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As said by some comments, when uploading using PHP, you need to give writing permissions to the upload directory. If you use filezilla, simply rightclick on the folder on the server, click fileattributes, and set it to, for example 775.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem just yesterday.  My problem was that my upload_max_filesize, located in the php.ini, was set to 2M.  I boosted it up to 4M and TADA, problem solved.  If you do seem to be having the same issue, don't forget to restart your server. ;)